Is uncertainty relative?
The analogy is capturing a fan that is rotating fast, where a camera that has a lower frame rate captures the blur result.
Suppose the fan has four blades painted with red for three blades. With such fast movement, a camera that only captures (measurement) once (momentum) will result in a blurry photo (uncertain position). But the probability of red seems higher than other though the value of probability value is not known yet.
Thus, it needs to capture repeatedly (more measurement) so that the probability of a red blade is approximately 3/4.
Does it mean the same for the quantum realm, where the quantum realm has a higher clock tick rate than our classical clock tick rate which is using Plank unit.
Which means quantum realm is actually deterministic while the classical realm (observer) perceive that as probabilistic / uncertain.
Analogy summaries:

Camera (measurement device)
Pixel (particle, but also wave since red is visible color)
Rotating Blade (Event)
One-time measurement (Blurry Photo)
More measurements (List of Blurry Photo so the probability and distribution of red pixel can be analyzed whether it's approximately 3/4 or not in the realm that faster than camera frame rate itself)


This is a physical question, not a philosophy question. My immediate reaction is that your theory does not address the double slit experiment, but for a more detailed analysis take it to the physics stack.

@keshlam One-shot photon is not enough to create wave interference pattern, thus it needs to be shot many times (observing over time) so that the final position of photons are clear, constructing distribution probability of every position.

Websearch "single photon double slit experiment".

@keshlam Yes, I admitted my argument was wrong. One-shot photon will still constructing wave interference.

You are looking for what is called a "local hidden variables theory".  This is testable and the answer seems to be no.

No, your fan analogy is incorrect. Quantum uncertainty in relation to momentum and position is much more fundamental.
According to quantum theory, particles have associated mathematical functions called 'wave functions'. The uncertainty in the momentum of a particle is determined by the frequency spectrum of the wave, while the position could be anywhere within the spatial spread of the wave. You can only have a wave with a single frequency (which here corresponds to an exact momentum), if it is spread throughout space, in which case the particle could be anywhere. Conversely, you can only have a wave that is very tightly confined in space (ie giving a definite position for the particle) if it has a huge spread of frequency components (ie the momentum uncertainty is extremely large).
It is impossible, therefore, to have a particle whose momentum and position have exact values, since when the particle's wave function corresponds to an exact position it is nothing like a wave function that corresponds to an exact momentum, and vice versa.

What is the difference with frequency of frame rate camera that analog to device measurement in QM (sampler), and the blade that spinning faster than camera frame rate, that analog with actual wave freq quanta as object that faster than measurement device?

I saw your interesting answer in physic SE about "How to measure time?". We are using periodic event tick to measure the time, such as caesium atom as reference for the wall clock. So, does it mean every device has its own universe tick? Like the sampler itself who captured the event? I don't really know what kind of sampler in Physic experiment (since I'm computer engineering student), it's abstracted in quantum computing. So, the sampler (observer) and the event following Nyquist theorem as answered by @nielsnielsen

Does it mean 8MHz crystal oscillator (that slower than caesium atom) perceive caesium atom state as uncertainty? While the caesium atom itself deterministic on its own tick? Considering the non/harmonicity.


Is uncertainty relative?

Certainty, and therefore uncertainty, is a psychological condition, so it is indeed relative to a sentient subject.
The notion of quantum uncertainty is still relative. We are uncertain of, for example, the position of a particle. Quantum mechanics explains why. Because there is a fundamental uncertainly not in the position of the particle, but what we infer is the position of the particle given the measure that we made. Given a different measure, there would be no uncertainty. The uncertainty is not in the position of the particle.

what if sentient subject is replaced by observer device?

@MuhammadIkhwanPerwira: the usual answer is that the observer device then becomes part of the quantum system, and the systems state is not resolved until an observer looks at the device. This applies even if the device is a person; Schrodinger's cat could be a human. And yes, this leads to regressions and recursions that will hurt your head. In human terms, quantum physics is ridiculous. Unfortunately, it does seem to be the best model of the universe we have; its predictions are testable, no test has refuted it yet, and it produces correct results where other models do not.

@MuhammadIkhwanPerwira "what if sentient subject is replaced by observer device?" You'd have to ask the device. But any measure is relative to the measure unit. Presumably, the device is certain. Any physical system can perform conditional actions, actions conditioned on the value of some measure. I would say that this is certainty. Of course, we only believe this because we can ourselves observe what mechanical devices do and why. We're certain that they are certain. Seems good enough for action and, crucially, survival.
